# How to send a file to a server using JSON and jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, file-upload, upload

I've to send a file to my server using jQuery. How can I do it using JSON?

The file type is not important, I intend to receive a byteArray or something like that on my server application.

If it helps I'm using an ASP.NET application, but my problem is not the way I handle that on server side, the issue is how to send the file data using jQuery.

I've found some upload plugins for jQuery that use a Flash file, others that do not use Flash, but what I really want to know is how the process works, not just use something already created by someone!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery is JavaScript. I think you mean to send the data via Ajax <strike>which can not be done. The best thing you can do is to use an iframe to a page that uploads the file to a temporary directory (not the default temp), and then provides the information back to the parent page as to where the file is saved then you use it.</strike>

There is no way to upload a file to a server using Ajax. It's too insecure.

I retract the Statement above NOW

You are now able to post/download file data using Javascript it's very complicated for a novice to understand but is now possible unlike when this question was answered

[Using HTML5 file uploads with AJAX and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery)

Answer (score 2):

File uploads won't work through an AJAX request.  It needs to be a full HTTP request (POST).  Any jQuery plugins that are used typically use either a Flash- or Java-based applet or the hidden iframe trick where a real POST is done using an iframe hidden on the page.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried it using $.ajaxFileUpload (http://www.phpletter.com/Demo/AjaxFileUpload-Demo/) and if you are using ASP.NET MVC you can retrieve the files as follows

```
  public ActionResult UploadFiles(List<HttpPostedFileBase> uFile)
```

Usage of $.ajaxFileUpload:

```
  $.ajaxFileUpload
(
    {
        url: "/Controller/UploadFiles", 
        secureuri: false,
        fileElementId: 'uFile', // the id of the file input controls holding the references to the files
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, status) {
            // needs to handle the json return
        },
        error: function (data, status, e) {
            // same as error
        }
    }
)
```

For me it works very well.

Answer (score 1):

You can invoke an HTTP Post using $.ajax, you dont have to do any manual labor manipulating the file content to json.  The payload will be in the HTTP Request if your form contains an input (type="file").  I can send a code sample if you can give me more detail about your code.

Comment: i'm planning the process, just checking the possibilities to do that. if you have some working code, that could helps i appreciate that very much. tnkx

Comment: My problem is not the server-side, what i dont know is how to send a file to the server usign a Client-side script like jquery. But i'm using webforms

Answer (score -2):

I highly recommend using valum's [plugin](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) for this.  It has a lot of support and is consistently updated as browsers begin implementing HTML5 support such as FileReader, etc.  Making it easier and easier to send "AJAX" file requests.

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=valums

**EDIT:**  Sorry for not reading your question fully - I read the title, read the first couple paragraphs and thought I knew what you were looking for.  It happened to be that the last paragraph held an exclusionary clause that I didn't see.

Comment: As i did mentioned, i'm looking to know about the process how it works!

Comment: Oops, I thought you were asking a concise programming question.  Read the source.

Comment: appreciated very much your response, but you i've mentioned (last paragraph) that i'm not interedted on components!, i'm interested to learn about the process!!