# Uploading a file using ajax and php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html

I want to implement file uploading using ajax and php. I have a form input tag. I want that onchange event of the input tag, file will be uploaded to the server and I will get the path of the file in a variable in javascript! So, I want to remain on the same page and upload the file, get the file path in the javascript variable.

Any pseudo code, examples, or tutorials would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have uploaded the file using php. But it goes to the php page. I want to implement it remaining on the same page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Demo url:--

http://jquery.malsup.com/form/progress.html

You can download jQuery files from this url and add in html `<head>` tag

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js

http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js

Try this:

This is my html markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
<title>File Upload Progress Demo #1</title>
<style>
body { padding: 30px }
form { display: block; margin: 20px auto; background: #eee; border-radius: 10px; padding: 15px }

.progress { position:relative; width:400px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; border-radius: 3px; }
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>File Upload Progress Demo #1</h1>
    <code>&lt;input type="file" name="myfile"></code>
        <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="uploadedfile"><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload File to Server">
    </form>

    <div class="progress">
        <div class="bar"></div >
        <div class="percent">0%</div >
    </div>

    <div id="status"></div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>
<script>
(function() {

var bar = $('.bar');
var percent = $('.percent');
var status = $('#status');

$('form').ajaxForm({
    beforeSend: function() {
        status.empty();
        var percentVal = '0%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    uploadProgress: function(event, position, total, percentComplete) {
        var percentVal = percentComplete + '%';
        bar.width(percentVal)
        percent.html(percentVal);
    },
    complete: function(xhr) {
     bar.width("100%");
    percent.html("100%");
        status.html(xhr.responseText);
    }
}); 

})();       
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

My php code:

```
<?php
$target_path = "uploads/";

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']); 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
    echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). 
    " has been uploaded";
} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}
?>
```

Comment: I love this thank you. There are too many people out there trying to make things do all sorts of unnecessary stuff. This is simple and works thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is one way and how I did it. Working with XHR. I have it up and running as we speak

[Using HTML5 file uploads with AJAX and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery)

http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#FileReader-interface

```
$(':file').change(function(){
            var file = this.files[0];
            name = file.name;
            size = file.size;
            type = file.type;

            if(file.name.length < 1) {

            }
            else if(file.size > 100000) {
                alert("File is to big");
            }
            else if(file.type != 'image/png' && file.type != 'image/jpg' && !file.type != 'image/gif' && file.type != 'image/jpeg' ) {
                alert("File doesnt match png, jpg or gif");
            }
            else { 
                $(':submit').click(function(){
                    var formData = new FormData($('*formId*')[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'script',  //server script to process data
                        type: 'POST',
                        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
                            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                            if(myXhr.upload){ // if upload property exists
                                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); // progressbar
                            }
                            return myXhr;
                        },
                        //Ajax events
                        success: completeHandler = function(data) {
                            /*
                            * workaround for crome browser // delete the fakepath
                            */
                            if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome')) {
                                var catchFile = $(":file").val().replace(/C:\\fakepath\\/i, '');
                            }
                            else {
                                var catchFile = $(":file").val();
                            }
                            var writeFile = $(":file");

                            writeFile.html(writer(catchFile));

                            $("*setIdOfImageInHiddenInput*").val(data.logo_id);

                        },
                        error: errorHandler = function() {
                            alert("Något gick fel");
                        },
                        // Form data
                        data: formData,
                        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false
                    }, 'json');
                });
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably check out some of the cool jQuery plugins, that can do the job for you, the two popular plugins are.

http://www.uploadify.com/

http://www.plupload.com/