# using html5 for file upload with ajax and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, file-upload

So i am trying to upload an image along with form data to server. I'm using FileReader API to convert image to data and upload to server. I'm following the code similar to [HTML5 uploader using AJAX Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery).

The data is converted in jquery, but nothing is being sent to server and there is no error generated.

```
$('#formupload').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var hasError = false;
    var file = document.getElementById('file').files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = shipOff;

    function shipOff(event) {
        result = new Image(); 
        result.src = event.target.result;
        var fileName = document.getElementById('file').files[0].name; 
        $.post('test.php', { data: result, name: fileName });
    }
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
$data = $_POST['data'];
$fileName = $_POST['name'];
echo $fileName;
$fp = fopen('/uploads/'.$fileName,'w'); //Prepends timestamp to prevent overwriting
fwrite($fp, $data);
fclose($fp);
$returnData = array( "serverFile" => $fileName );
echo json_encode($returnData);
?>
```

Is the problem due to large image file or FileReader API?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure if file upload works with filereaders, but there is a different way to make it work:

```
var formData = new FormData($(".file_upload_form")[0]);
$.ajax({
    url: "upload_file.php", // server script to process data (POST !!!)
    type: 'POST',
    xhr: function() { // custom xhr
        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
        if (myXhr.upload) { // check if upload property exists
            // for handling the progress of the upload
            myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progressHandlingFunction, false); 
        }
        return myXhr;
    },
    success: function(result) {
        console.log($.ajaxSettings.xhr().upload);
        alert(result);
    },
    // Form data
    data: formData,
    //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
    cache: false,
    contentType: "application/octet-stream", // Helps recognize data as bytes
    processData: false
});

function progressHandlingFunction(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable) {
        $("#progress").text(e.loaded + " / " + e.total);
    }
}
```

This way you send the data to the PHP file and you can use `$_FILES` to process it. Unfortunately, this does not work in IE as far as I know. There might be plugins available that make this possible in IE, but I don't know any of them.

Comment: This code would only send the image to server. I need to send the image along with rest of form data at same time.  I was able to send the data to server had to replace /uploads/ with uploads/. But image content cannot be opened

Comment: @de-bugged this actually will send the image and the data, `var formData = new FormData($('.file_upload_form')[0]);` will make sure of that. The form can contain file uploads and other data at the same time and will simply convert it to a normal `$_POST` value. If you have a text input with the name `text`, that one will also be accessible within the `$_POST`.

Comment: @de-bugged if this helped you, please press the accept button next to this answer :)

Comment: Hi Rune, Tried your method. The content of the formData is append:function append() and no other form data. Ive also tried to append all form data into formData and call post request. no data is sent to server. Any suggestions?

Comment: and also undefined content from PHP side.

Comment: @de-bugged That is strange, because I use the exact same code, and it works perfectly for me. Can you show me the code you are using? You can paste it in a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: I must have messed up the code somewhere. The code is at http://jsfiddle.net/AzJW4/ Any help would be great.

Comment: @de-bugged I don't see anything that might fail it.. Do you get the success call back, or does it error somewhere? There might be an error in your PHP script that causes it too.

Comment: Since my formData content is empty i never had the thot of chking the php code. Yes i received call back. I print the content of data in server and its undefined content. I use $data = $_POST['data']; to receive the content. Im receiving it wrong?

Comment: To get the postdata you just use the `name`s of the elements the data is in, that works just like a normal post. So you'd need to have `$_POST['caption']` and `$_FILES['file']` in your case. Or you can do `print_r($_POST)` to check what is in there.

Comment: You deserve a + 1,000,000,000 on this..  been searching for a cross-domain solution that would work all day and yours was the only one that did.  Thanks!

Comment: Using `contentType: "application/octet-stream"` may help with some servers