# Multi-Step Form with File Upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, file-upload

I have a multi-step form. What I want to achieve here is **to allow user to upload a file (with some validation using jquery.validate plugin) and store the file to mySQL database.**

Previously, I wasnt using multi-step form design (a one-page per step design instead) and therefore when user clicked the "submit" button, I would have `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` and `$_FILES` to validate the file through PHP. Below is the PHP code that will be triggered when user clicked "submit" button .

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{   
    $allowedExts = array("mov", "mp4", "mpeg", "wmv");
    $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $extension = end($temp);
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/quicktime") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mp4") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/mpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "video/x-ms-wmv")) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts) && (!empty($_POST["title"])) && (!empty($_POST["description"])))
    {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
        {
            echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        }
        else
        {
                 // check if the file already exist in Uploaded folder
            if (file_exists("uploaded/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]))
            {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]." already exists. ";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<br />".$_FILES["file"]["name"]." has been uploaded! <br /><br />";
                echo "Upload: ".$_FILES["file"]["name"]."<br />";
                echo "Type: ".$_FILES["file"]["type"]."<br />";
                echo "Size: ".($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024)." kB<br />";
                echo "Stored in: "."uploaded/".$_FILES["file"]["name"];
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploaded/".$_FILES["file"]["name"]);
                $name = $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                $url = "";      //some URL
                mysql_query("INSERT INTO video (name, title, description, url) VALUES ('$name', '$title', '$description', '$url')") or die(mysql_error());
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (!empty($_POST["description"]) && (!empty($_POST["title"])))
        {
            echo "Invalid file";
        }   
    }
}
```

But now, since I have change my design to multi-step form, this logic seems not working anymore. This is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NZr4n/2/).

I was thinking to change the "Upload" button type from `type="button"` to `type="submit"`so that I can use my old PHP logic to process the file and upload to database, however this causes my multi-step form to stop going to the next step.

Any brilliant ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid page reloads, you could try posting the form through a hidden iframe and then reading the response on load. As far as I know this should work in all browsers

```
<iframe name="target_iframe">..</iframe>

<form target="target_iframe">..</form>
```

Check out [How do you post to an iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/168455/how-do-you-post-to-an-iframe)

If you're happy dropping support for older browsers you can post files using ajax. Maybe check out [using html5 for file upload with ajax and jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455529/using-html5-for-file-upload-with-ajax-and-jquery)