# How do you upload a file to a http web page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, http

I have recently used [www.codecademy.com](http://www.codecademy.com) to teach myself HTML, CSS and JavaScript.
I have had minimal coding experience prior to this so I'm not too hot on how everything works and the lessons that I went through only covered general, everyday code.
I have looked online for a suitable tutorial/run down of how to go about it but I haven't found one I think is suitable.
I was wondering if anyone knows of any resources that I could use to help me learn this.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

---

HTML/CSS learnt:

- Importing scripts and stylesheets
- Common HTML tags
- Creating IDs and Classes
- Tables, Divs, Spans
- General CSS and Positioning

JavaScript Learnt:

- Functions
- For/While Loops
- Switch statements
- Objects and Arrays

Comment: If you mean uploading files with HTML5 and AJAX, it is possible - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery

Comment: Good job, I'm glad you're learning and you have desire to learn more, however here at stackoverflow you need to ask much more specific questions. Check the FAQ for more info -> http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.
I'm finding this coding lark really interesting and want to learn more about what it can do, and how I can do that myself.
I've no idea what AJAX and all these other things are but I'll have a look around and see what I can find.
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are plentiful of resources regarding javascript (ajax) file upload components out there. There's really no other (good) way to learn this than diving down into some code and trying to get a grip on it. One good place to start would be one of the known javascript frameworks, like [jQuery](http://jquery.com), [MooTools](http://mootools.net/) etc. Most of them have a decent collection of plugins that might do what you need.

Comment: I did a few things using jQuery but it only showed me how to use effects and animation.
I had no idea it could be used for this! Thanks for your answer.