# how to upload files through REST?

Tags: jquery, ajax, rest, file-upload

I am having trouble trying to upload a file through rest. I read a lot about it, mostly in this forum; however i didn't really find how to do it.

in the backend, the upload works. I have tested it using a simple form data. But I don't know how to do it with jquery's ajax. I have set `enctype: 'multipart/form-data'` in ajax but I do not know how to send both meta data and the actual file as is to my server. I thought of putting the meta data in the headers but it would be great if I can send it through a post request.

Thanks,
Gasim

Comment: Since i am using a browser extension, i used html5 formdata model and it works. But I still have a problem. Is there any way I can fake a file creation? I want to pass a fake file to my server from a string.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML5 file uploads with AJAX and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery)