# send data with javascript FormData()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My code has one input tag and send it to my php file by using jquery FormData()
now i want add another input tag and send more data.
jquery it's:

```
var files = document.getElementById('data-file').files;
var data = new FormData();

$.each(files, function (keys, values) {
    data.append(keys, values);
});
$.ajax({
    url: 'upload.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
});
```

and html code is:

```
<input style="display:none;" type="file" name="data-file" id="data-file" onchange="image_preview(this)" multiple="multiple" />
```

i want change html to this and send input data to php file by using jquery FormData():

```
<input style="display:none;" type="file" name="data-file" id="data-file" onchange="image_preview(this)" multiple="multiple" />
<input type="hidden" name="imgpath" id="imgpath" value="<?php echo $imgpath; ?>"  />
<input type="hidden" name="id" id="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"  />
```

Comment: jQuery has no FormData, that would be native javascript.

Comment: And if you stick your inputs in a form, you could just pass the form to FormData

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using HTML5 file uploads with AJAX and jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [FormData's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) [append](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Using_FormData_Objects#Creating_a_FormData_object_from_scratch) method to add additional key values to the `FormData` as you did within `$.each`

for eg.

```
$.each(files, function (keys, values) {
    data.append(keys, values);
});

data.append('imgpath', $('#imgpath').val());
data.append('id', $('#id').val());
```