# jQuery $.post sending image file to servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I have `javaee` project. I want to send image file to my servlet via ajax.
Ajax not sending image file to my java class. But it is sending textarea value.
Here is my form

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" beanclass="ActionBean">
    <input type="file" id="uploadFile" name="newAttachment"/>
    <textarea name="name" id="name" rows="2" cols="30"></textarea>
    <s:submit value="Edit" name="saveOfferInfo" onclick="return edit(this);" />
```

JavaScript function:

```
function edit(button) {
    var form = button.form;
    var params = $(form).serializeArray();
    params.push({name: '_eventName', value: button.name});
    $.post(form.action, params, function (data) {
        alert("success");
});
```

Comment: If the answer helped you, please consider upvoting/accepting. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the doc of [`$.serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/), it specifically says that

> Data from file select elements is not serialized.

Unfortunately, uploading file in AJAX isn't as straight forward. There is a detailed tutorial [here](http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax) using straight-up JQuery. The gist of it is that you need to:

1. Bind the file input to a `change` event handler,
2. Gather all the form data in a [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) object,
3. Then POST the form data using the [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) function.

Too much work?

Alternately, if you don't mind including plugins in your codes, here are some options:

1. [jQuery-Ajax-File-Upload](https://github.com/Abban/jQuery-Ajax-File-Upload)
2. [jquery-form](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/)

Or as Rohan pointed out, if you are using HTML5, you can explore the [FileReader API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#FileReader-interface).

Answer (score 0):

File upload is not possible using AJAX, check for further details

> First of all I have to say that to create a pure AJAX file upload
>   system is not possible because of security limitations of JavaScript.
>   All of the Ajax upload systems I know use some third party
>   tool/package or only mimics the AJAX feeling. Even so it makes file
>   upload process a bit nicer. In the next section I will present you a
>   solution which imitates the AJAX process, but uses a normal upload
>   process and iFrames.

The concept:

- Create a simple HTML form for file upload
- Set the target to an iFrame which is on the actual page but not visible
- Call a JavaScript function on form submit to display the animation
- After the PHP part finishes the upload process, then it hides the animation

[Read more](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html#)

If you don't bother about older browser versions and want to code for the latest browsers then you can use [FileReader API](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#FileReader-interface) See [Using HTML5 file uploads with AJAX and jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery)