# Copy file from local to the server nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am using nodeJS and I would like to upload a file to the server.
I have pug page where the user fill all the information and choose a file with filechooser. Then I want to send all the information on the page to the server. Therefore, I am using ajax to send a json object and given that file object can not be send through a json object I convert the File object to a json object like this:

```
function uploadGenome() {
    var file = $(':file')[0].files[0];
    var fileObject = {
        'lastMod': file.lastModified,
        'lastModDate': file.lastModifiedDate,
        'name': file.name,
        'size': file.size,
        'type': file.type
    };
    return fileObject;
}
```

Then I add everything in a Json object:

```
    var data = {};
    data.file = uploadGenome();
    data.name = inputs[0].value;
    data.description = inputs[1].value;
    data.start = inputs[3].value;
    data.end = inputs[4].value;
```

And finally, I send everything with ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        url: url,
        success: function (data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
            if (data === 'done')
            {
                window.location.href = "/";
            } else {
                alert('Error Creating the Instance');
            }
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log('process error');
        }
    });
```

On the server side with NodeJS I get everything, but now how could I copy the file that I get in data.file on the server ? I mean create a copy on the project folder which is on a server.

Comment: What are you asking? You're saying you're getting the information on the server. Just create a new file with the contents of the received information. https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: No, in fact, I save the information data.name, data.description, data.start and data.end in a database. And I would like at the same time to copy the file @SimonHyll

Comment: It looks like you never transfer the file itself as your payload just contains file metadata.

Comment: I have seen that I could use formData but it means that I will have to send two ajax one for the file and one for the information (description, start, end, name) that I want to save to the database @lukas293

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006520/using-html5-file-uploads-with-ajax-and-jquery

Comment: Alright, basically he is reading the content of the file and then sending it. Thanks

Comment: Add `file: 'contents as string'` to the json object that you're sending, you don't need any special magic to send a file.